# List of symbols with glossaries -- problem with using \underline

Tags: formatting, glossaries, text-decorations

I'm having a weird problem with glossaries (TeXLive 2011, glossaries v3.01), illustrated by the following example:

```
% compile this with
%    pdflatex example.tex
%    makeindex  -s "example.ist" -t "example.alg" -o "example.acr" "example.acn"
%    pdflatex example.tex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbole}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{#1}}
%\newcommand{\cvect}[1]{\overline{\vect{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cvect}[1]{\underline{\vect{#1}}}

\newglossaryentry{sym:sc}{name={\ensuremath{\cvect{s}}},description={some complex vector},type=symbolslist}

\begin{document}

\gls{sym:sc}

\ensuremath{\underline{\bm{s}}}

\printglossary[type=symbolslist]

\end{document}
```

In my document, I need to typeset complex-valued vectors in boldfaced, italic letters with a line below, see the `\cvect` definition. This works as expected, except if I'm trying to use it for a symbol definition along with the `glossaries` package. Then, the `pdflatex` run is interrupted with a `missing $` error.

The weird thing about this is: if I use `\overline` instead of `\underline` in the definition of `\cvect`, everything works as expected (see the commented version of `\cvect`).

My first idea was that this could be a problem with `\ensuremath`, however, when using it without `\newglossaryentry` (i.e., just in the document body), it works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\underline` is not robust. Try something like this:

```
\newcommand\cvect{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cvect[1]{\underline{\vect{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation of glossaries you can find the following hint:

> **sort**
>   This value indicates how `makeindex` or `xindy` should sort this
>   entry. If omitted, the value is given by the name field. In general,
>   it’s best to use the sort key if the name contains commands (e.g.
>   `\ensuremath{\alpha}`). Note that the package options `sort=def` and
>   `sort=use` override the sort key in `\newglossaryentry`.

Ulrike mentioned that `\underline` isn't robust. Instead of `\underline` you can use the command `\uline` provided by the package [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem)

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\cvect}[1]{\uline{\ensuremath{\vect{#1}}}}

\newglossaryentry{sym:sc}{sort=s,name={\cvect{s}},description={some complex vector},type=symbolslist}
```

Christoph Spiegel mentioned the very interesting information of the documentation `ulem`:

> The various underlining commands are essentially textual, and will not
>   work quite the same in math mode. But since some font commands, in A
>   the old-L TEX style (‘oldlfont’) serve both for text and math, math
>   mode is handled (in an approximate way). Generally, you should avoid
>   using ulem’s commands within math, but math may appear in the text
>   argument to ulem’s commands.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my minimal example, I omitted the `sort` parameter of `\newglossaryentry`. In my actual document, I'm using text-only tags for the `sort` parameter for exactly the reason that is mentioned in the `glossaries` manual. Thanks for then hint with `\ulem` anyway!

Comment: In the `ulem` docs, it says: "Generally, you should avoid using ulem’s commands within math, but math may appear in the text argument to ulem’s commands." -- I think one should therefore better not use it with math.

Comment: @christoph.spiegel: You are right. Thanks. I had never read this. Now `\uline` is outside the math-environment ;-)

Comment: I see :), but that won't work for me since I will usually have an index for such a vector (like `\cvect{s}_\mathrm{1}`), which shall not be included in the underlining. So I'll better stick to Ulrike's suggestion.

Comment: @christoph.spiegel: Of course ;-)