# underline doesn't work in `newglossaryentry` (sharelatex)

Tags: glossaries, underline

```
%\newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{{\epsilon}},description={Complex relative permittivity of a material}} 
\newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{\underline{\epsilon}},description={Complex relative permittivity of a material}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok, i understand, i will do it next time, i have a solution for this, i just put underline before gls and it works  \underline{\gls{Perm}} not a very beautiful solution, but it works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solve problem himself as said in comment.

Comment: You should write `name={{\underline{$\epsilon$}}}` (and provide a sort option).  Note how many braces are needed and the placing of math mode.

Comment: Probably a duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34219/154602